# room db multiple column subquery

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
select * from generic_shop 
    where (type, timestamp) in (
        select  type, max(timestamp) 
            from generic_shop 
            group by type
    ) order by type
```

This query works if tested in the command line but on a room it claims there is an error at `where (type, timestamp)`. How do I rewrite this to get it working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQLite does not support multi-column `WHERE IN` clauses.  Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Also, `group by type` does not really work well with `select *`.  You should also tell us the logic behind your query.

Comment: this query basically ought to return the last entry to the db for each type based on the largest timestamp of that type

Comment: I'm really surprised your query ran at all on SQLite.  If you can find a doc reference supporting this syntax, I'd like to see it.  In the meantime, I gave you an alternative you may use to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support `IN` clauses involving more than one column on the left hand side.  But, your query is easy enough to express using other means:

```
SELECT g1.*
FROM generic_shop g1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM generic_shop
    GROUP BY type
) g2
    ON g1.type = g2.type AND g1.timestamp = g2.max_timestamp;
ORDER BY
    g1.type;
```